# Detect any event in Angular library

Tags: angular, events

I have container and in container I have custom Angular library. I should get any changes (for example click on button in container) from container in library.

Could anyone help me with this ?

Thanks

Comment: `I have custom Angular library` : What does it mean? You could have a generic service in your library that holds a `Subject` that gets updated whenever something changes and in the FE you can simply `subscribe` to it to register - and do stuff - with it.

Comment: 'Custom Angular library' is my library... yes, I tried with Subject but 'subscribe' I can not detect in component in library.